# Eliminating extra rows in nested selects

Tags: sql-server, select, nested, duplicates

I am trying to get the specific UserRating by month for a specified range.  When I use this below, it works, with no extra rows:

```
Select 

Distinct(Table2.AccountNumber), 

Jan11=Case 
When Datepart(yy,Org.Billdate)=2011 and Datepart(mm,Org.Billdate) = 01 then         Table2.UserRating
    END

From (

Select Distinct(Table1.AccountNumber) as UseThisNumber, Table1.RegionID as UseThisRegionID

From AccountDetail Table1 
Where Table1.RegionID in (  

Select Distinct(Reg.RegionID) 
From RegionOrganizationTable Reg  where Datepart(yy,Reg.Billdate)=2011 and         Datepart(mm,Reg.Billdate) = 01) and
    Table1.UserRating in (‘Very Satisfied’, ‘Mostly Satisfied, ‘Satisfied’)
    Group by Table1.AccountNumber, Table1.RegionID) GroupedValues, 

AccountDetail Table2
RegionOrganizationTable  Org

Where Table2.AccountNumber =GroupedValues.UseThisNumber 
and Table2 UseThisRegionID=GroupedValues.UseThisRegionID
and Org.RegionID= GroupedValues.UseThisRegionID

Order by Table2.AccountNumber
```

However, when I change the Datepart criteria in the nested component to:

```
Datepart(yy,Reg.Billdate)>2010
```

(as this is really the date range I want to examine), and remove:

```
Datepart(mm,Reg.Billdate)=01
```

all of the previously qualifying AccountNumbers from January 2011 are repeated but return a NULL value.  This is compounded when I add the other months (i.e. Feb11=Case when....)

Here is what the output looks like in first scenario:

AccountNumber.....Jan11
123456...................Very Satisfied
143457...................Mostly Satisfied
163458...................Satisfied
183459...................Very Satisfied
203460...................Very Satisfied

And here's the second (I **BOLDED** the duplicates here for easier recognition)

AccountNumber.....Jan11
**123456...................Very Satisfied

123456...................NULL**
123499...................NULL
133499...................NULL
**143457...................Mostly Satisfied

143457...................NULL**
143499...................NULL
153499...................NULL
**163458...................NULL

163458...................Satisfied**
173458...................NULL
173499...................NULL
**183459...................Very Satisfied

183459...................NULL**
183499...................NULL
193459...................NULL
**203460...................NULL

203460...................Very Satisfied**

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you mean `YEAR`, say `YEAR`, if you mean `MONTH`, say `MONTH`. These shorthand are lazy cans of worms. Try `SELECT DATEPART(y, GETDATE());` to see what I mean.

Comment: And if you show some sample data and desired results (perhaps using http://sqlfiddle.com/), we can probably write a much better query than trying to fix what you have here. `DISTINCT()` around individual column names and all of these nested subqueries and subselects make me believe the actual query you need is much simpler.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for the feedback.  I am a newbie hacking my way through this and it shows :) At any rate, I edited the OP to show the output results.